# Javascript - how to set up third option on code with only double choice

Tags: javascript, css

Now problem is that i want have three options when there are only two and after simply correction code doesnt works. I want work with this "A simple mod". How to set up for final solve with three options?
I dont understand a lot from this code but i learn that mostly the solution isnt so difficult.
Whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/teocci/Lnt9quLu/

```css
.cc-selector input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.cc-selector-2 input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

.visa {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png);
}

.mastercard {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png);
}

.cc-selector-2 input:active+.drinkcard-cc,
.cc-selector input:active+.drinkcard-cc {
  opacity: .9;
}

.cc-selector-2 input:checked+.drinkcard-cc,
.cc-selector input:checked+.drinkcard-cc {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}

.drinkcard-cc {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}

.drinkcard-cc:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}


/* Extras */

a:visited {
  color: #888
}

a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}

* {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.cc-selector-2 input {
  margin: 5px 0 0 12px;
}

.cc-selector-2 label {
  margin-left: 7px;
}

span.cc {
  color: #6d84b4
}
```

```html
<p>A simple mod:</p>
<div class="cc-selector-2">
  <input id="visa2" type="radio" name="creditcard" value="visa" />
  <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa2"></label>
  <input checked="checked" id="mastercard2" type="radio" name="creditcard" value="mastercard" />
  <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard" for="mastercard2"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem

Just copy and paste another card with another class

```css
.cc-selector input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.cc-selector-2 input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

.visa {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png);
}

.mastercard {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png);
}

.americanExpress {
  background-image: url(https://icm.aexp-static.com/Internet/internationalcardshop/nl_nl/images/cards/green-card.png)
}

.cc-selector-2 input:active+.drinkcard-cc,
.cc-selector input:active+.drinkcard-cc {
  opacity: .9;
}

.cc-selector-2 input:checked+.drinkcard-cc,
.cc-selector input:checked+.drinkcard-cc {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}

.drinkcard-cc {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}

.drinkcard-cc:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}


/* Extras */

a:visited {
  color: #888
}

a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}

* {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.cc-selector-2 input {
  margin: 5px 0 0 12px;
}

.cc-selector-2 label {
  margin-left: 7px;
}

span.cc {
  color: #6d84b4
}
```

```html
<p>A simple mod:</p>
<div class="cc-selector-2">
  <input id="visa2" type="radio" name="creditcard" value="visa" />
  <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa2"></label>

  <input checked="checked" id="mastercard2" type="radio" name="creditcard" value="mastercard" />
  <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard" for="mastercard2"></label>

  <input id="americanExpress" type="radio" name="creditcard" value="AE" />
  <label class="drinkcard-cc americanExpress" for="americanExpress"></label>
</div>
```